# CefSharp - How to handle "This page has insecure content." message?

Tags: ajax, security, jsonp, chromium

I am using the [CefSharp](https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp) .Net wrapper for the Chromium Embedded Framework as a simple wrapper around a web application. In my web application, I make a JSONP AJAX call out to another domain to get some data and display it. The URL to that domain is *not* using SSL. Because of that, when doing this in the Chrome browser, I get the following message, to which the end user would simply click "Load Anyway", allowing the JSONP request to fire and the data to be retrieved...

[image]

The app using CefSharp simply starts up the main URL to my web application when it runs. When I try and make the same call in my this application using CefSharp, however, it doesn't get that same prompt. Instead, the AJAX request just times out (the same behavior that happens when the end user never clicks a button in the yellow bar that appears in Chrome).

Does anyone know if CefSharp has a way for me to catch this security message and either...

1. Prompt the end user to click "Load anyway", similar to the behavior of the Chrome browser, or
2. Programmatically bypass the security warning altogether?

If not, does the Chromium Framework itself support dealing with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting to [CefSharp](https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp/issues/71) and [CEF](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=799) projects, it looks like CEF does not currently support this situation. magreenblatt suggested a couple of approaches to add it to CEF. Now I just need to try and find the time to add support for it. :-)